# The map $G$ from a solid of revolution $M$ to a set of its unit normals isn't injective

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> Let $(f(t),0,g(t)),t\in [0,L]$ be a smooth curve satisfying
>   $f(0)=f(L)$.Denote the solid formed by revolving the curve around the
>   $z$-axis as (by) $M$. Suppose $G:M\to \Bbb{S}^2$ is a continuous map
>   mapping every $u\in M$ to a unit normal vector to $M$.
>
> 1. Is $G$ injective?
> 2. Is $G$ surjective?

**Remark:** a unit normal to hypersurface $M$ at $x$ is a vector $v\in (T_x{M})^{\bot}$ such that $|v|=1$,($T_xM$ being the tangent space of M at x).

I am currently stuck showing it is not necessarily injective but I am not quite sure I know what to do. I had some ideas referring me to repetitive patterns in the original curve. For example,I wondered what if $M$ contains two vectors that share the same tangent space and what it can say. But eventually, I cannot presume $G$ maps $x$ to a normal correspondent to that orthogonal to $TxM$. In other words, I am quite lost here. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A counterexample for injectivity for a closed curve is the torus, which may be given by revolving a circle that does not intersect the $z$-axis around the $z$-axis. Given any direction, there are two places with a parallel normal vector (on opposite sides). Another example for a non-closed curve is to take $g(t)=t$, $f(t)$ a quadric with several extrema ($t(L-t)(1-3t(L-t))$ will do), and then you have multiple places where the tangent is parallel.

Surjectivity is related to smoothness of the surface: if the surface formed is smooth at every point, given any plane, you can slide it towards the surface until it is tangent at a point $P$, say, and then $P$ has the required normal. To show smoothness is required, one can consider the [lemon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Lemon.html), given by revolving a smaller-than-semicircular arc: it is easy to see that the normals to the curve only cover an annulus on the sphere, missing regions near the poles.

Comment: But the curve here does include point from the $z$-axis, there is $(0,0,g(0)) $ and $(0,0,g(L))$?

Comment: Sorry, which case are you referring to?

Comment: I am so sorry, I have been remiss in noting all the details. It is required that $f(0)=f(L)=0$. Again, I am very sorry for making you waste your time. However, you gave me intuition which is really helpful.

Comment: The quartic and the lemon still work as examples. And you can just take the [apple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Apple.html) instead of the torus.